# The Stack Exchange app label is cu…

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

t off.

[image: what pray tell is this]

It would be nice if it was changed to just "Exchange" or "Stack" or something. The icon's already recognisable enough.

Comment: Well, at least it's the exchange that's overflowing, and not the stack.

Comment: It's the same on Android.

Comment: +1 for the title (and obviously for the bug :) - I was *really* baffled for a second there! I thought SE had added an *extra big* ellipses gap!

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce [nope](http://i.stack.imgur.com/88Onb.png) - though it might be different for each device. LG G3 for me, what's yours?

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce it's device dependent, related to the resolution bucket on different Android device and the launcher.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Moto X (2013)

Comment: *Pinterest?* Bro, do you even bro?